# How to get a String from another class inside an OnClickListener inside an OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android

I am trying to get a string from another class and use it at MainActivity. The string is initialized in an OnClickListener which is inside an OnItemClickListener.
I searched up some solutions but the method using the Intent is not working here because I am not switching between the activities and I want the String at MainActivity. I tried the method using SharedPreferences but it didnt work.
Here is the code for the class with the String

TimeForm

```
public class TimeForm extends AppCompatActivity{

public ArrayList<String> arrayList;
ListView dayListView;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private static List<String> fromArrayList;
ArrayList<String> untilArrayList;
public String currentDay;
EditText fromEditText;
EditText untilEditText;
EditText multiLineEditText;
ListView itemsListView;
Button submitButton;
EditText actionEditText;
private FirebaseFirestore db;
private static final String TAG = "TimeForm";

public String CurrentDay;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_form);

    //Variables==============================================================
    dayListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.dayListView);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final TextView dayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dayTextView);
    submitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    fromEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fromEditText);
    multiLineEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.actionEditText);
    untilEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.untilEditText);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    fromArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    untilArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter fromArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fromArrayList);
    ArrayAdapter untilArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, untilArrayList);
    itemsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.itemsListView);
    actionEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.actionEditText);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    arrayList.add("Monday");
    arrayList.add("Tuesday");
    arrayList.add("Wednesday");
    arrayList.add("Thursday");
    arrayList.add("Friday");
    arrayList.add("Saturday");
    arrayList.add("Sunday");
    final GlobalClass globalClass = (GlobalClass) this.getApplicationContext();
    dayListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    dayListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            TextView enterActionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.enterActionTextView);
            EditText actionEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.actionEditText);
            currentDay = arrayList.get(position);
            TextView enterTimeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.enterActionTextView);
            dayTextView.setText(currentDay);
            submitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
            submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final String fromText = fromEditText.getText().toString();
                    final String untilText = untilEditText.getText().toString();
                    final String actionText = multiLineEditText.getText().toString();

                    if(fromText.matches("") || untilText.matches("") || actionText.matches("")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill the whole Form", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{                                                     
                        Toast.makeText(TimeForm.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        globalClass.setTestString(actionText);
                        fromEditText.setText("");
                        untilEditText.setText("");
                        multiLineEditText.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nevigation_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent reportBugIntent = new Intent(TimeForm.this, com.anastasispap.schedulemaker.ReportBug.class);
    Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(TimeForm.this, MainActivity.class);
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_file:
            startActivity(timeFormIntent);
    }
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_reportbug){
        startActivity(reportBugIntent);
    }else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_home){
        startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
   }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

}
```

The String I want to get is the fromText, the untilText and the actionText. 
And I want those Strings to get them in MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView itemsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemsListView);
    final TextView itemsTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.itemsTextView);
    final ArrayList<String> itemsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final TextView dayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dayTextView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemsArrayList);

    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    dayTextView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(currentTime.getTime()));

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final GlobalClass globalClass = (GlobalClass) this.getApplicationContext();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, globalClass.getTestString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nevigation_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent timeFormIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimeForm.class);
    Intent reportBugIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReportBug.class);
    Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_file:
            startActivity(timeFormIntent);
    }
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_reportbug){
        startActivity(reportBugIntent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

Comment: where you have written this code ? I mean which class

Comment: This class is called TimeForm

Comment: Can you please share, how you calling this TimeForm from main activity ?

Comment: Calling it wont make a difference because the String is initialized when the button is pressed and I cant make a constructor and a getter at TimeForm class

Comment: Do you want the MainActivity and the TimeForm

Comment: What is **TimeForm** ? Is it adapter, Fragment, activity or any other class ? Is it get called from MainActivity ?

Comment: TimeForm is an Activity

Comment: If your `TimeForm` activity get launched from `MainActivity` then you may need to use `startActivityForResult` [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: To go to TimeForm activity I use a menu in the taskbar but I want to get the String I must do it inside the OnClickListener because I pass the value at the EditText then press the button and then it gets saved, so I am not sure on how to make the string public

Comment: I was thinking in adding the String in a database but I dont know how to access that particular database from MainActivity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a global class to store the string. And use that string from anywhere and in your code. And you can use getters and setters to access it.

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application {
    private String yourString;

    public String getYourString() {
        return yourString;
    }

    public void setYourString(String yourString) {
        this.yourString = yourString;
    }
}
```

Define this in the application tag of the manifest file

```
<application
    android:name=".GlobalClass"
```

and use it like this in the `onCreate` function of the activities you use this.

```
globalClass = (GlobalClass) this.getApplicationContext();
```

if it is not an activity, (pass the context of the activity using params)

```
globalClass = (GlobalClass) context.getApplicationContext();
```

then you can use getters and setters to access your strings.
setting values,

```
String fromString = "some value";
globalClass.setYourString(fromString)
```

getting values,

```
String fromString = globalClass.getYourString();
```

You can use this `GlobalClass` to store all your strings and any other values you need to access from multiple `activities` and `classes`

Comment: Seems like a solution, I will try that and I will comment again

Comment: I got this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.anastasispap.schedulemaker/com.anastasispap.schedulemaker.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to com.anastasispap.schedulemaker.GlobalClass

Comment: I fixed the bug but in MainActivity it doesnt return anything

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't return anything'?

Comment: I added an OnClickListener at MainActivity and a toast returning the String but it shows a plain Toast. But I did the same thing at TimeForm and I saw the text in the Toast

Comment: add the updated code of both activities to your question

Comment: you can't initialize the `GlobalClass` like that. As I instructed in the above code use `globalClass = (GlobalClass) this.getApplicationContext();`

Comment: Ahhh, ok ill try that. Thanks for everything, you are a big help

Comment: I get this error:                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.anastasispap.schedulemaker/com.anastasispap.schedulemaker.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to com.anastasispap.schedulemaker.GlobalClass

Comment: Try extending `GlobalClass` using `MultiDexApplication ` instead of `Application`

Comment: It WORKED!! Thank you so much.

Comment: I have one last question. Does this method work for arrayLists too?

Comment: yes. You can store any value in that class. and access from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making an interface for the main activity that takes in the strings.

```
public interface IMainActivity {
void fromText(String fromText);
void untilText(String untilText);
void actionText(String actionText);
}
```

Then pass the instance of the implementation into TimeForm (Dagger would be good here).

Comment: Thing is that I dont know how to get the String out of the OnClickListener